# Read HTML table using a web page URL pandas

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following url, I am trying to extract the table from the page but every time I run it takes forever and I have to manually stop it. I used other URL it works fine , but doesn't work for this specific URL.

```
dfs = pd.read_html('http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/ActionsByLocationServlet?requestid=1&allbin=1079215', header=0)
dfs[0].head()
```

### 2nd method

```
import requests  
r = requests.get('http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/ActionsByLocationServlet?requestid=1&allbin=1079215')

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

Appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: I ran the command in the first line and it ran fine. Took less than a second. Are you able to access the site from your browser without trouble?

Comment: Yes I can access the site but It doesn't run for me. It takes forever and doesn't give any error either. Did you get the exact same table as the webpage?

Comment: Can you `curl` the website? What happens if you manually download the html, save it as file and then supply the file as parameter to `pandas.read_html`? I.e., break up the steps for debugging.

Comment: Yea, it worked. I downloaded it as html and ran it like regular csv file with  'pd.read_html ' . Now, how do I extract the table from there?

Comment: Are you sure your code is not finishing because of `pandas.read_html`? To me it seems like everything should be working for you.

Comment: It worked but doesn't produce the output I was looking for. It doesn't show any tables after I ran it.